# Translating PHP $get_month from english to swedish

Tags: php, blogs, archive, setlocale

I have a blog archive that's in English and I want the month to display in Swedish instead. I've searched and tried answers to similar problems, but nothing is working. Can someone please help?

```
<?php
include 'includes/db_connection.php';
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%M %Y') AS get_month, COUNT(*) AS entries FROM php_blog GROUP BY get_month ORDER BY timestamp DESC"); ?>

<ul class="archive_list">
<br><br><br><br>
<ul class="archive_ul">
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE');

$get_month = $row['get_month'];
$entries = $row['entries'];
echo "<li><a href=\"archive.php?month=" . $get_month . "\">" . $get_month . "</a></li>";
}


//setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE');
//echo utf8_encode (strftime("%A %e %B %Y"));

?>
```

So in the link below I want the month to display in Swedish instead, and I'm using get_month  to extract it from my database. Any ideas? I really only need the name of the month that will be shown in the link to be translated. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

`setlocale()` sets the locale for PHP, but the Month name is being generated by MySQL which has its own settings. Try updating MySQL's locale with:

```
mysql_query("SET lc_time_names = 'sv_SE'");
```

*(this should replace your first instance of `setlocale()`, before your `SELECT ...` statement*

*NB: `mysql_*` functions are depreciated, you might want to consider using `mysqli_*` instead*

Comment: Thank you SO SO SO much! This worked! This archive has been driving me crazy for the longest time now. Thanks alot! :D

Answer (score 0):

If its only the month, have it put in an array with the month index and use google translate for the 12 months.

`$swedish_months = array('Januari','Februari','Mars','April','Maj','Juni','Juli','Augusti','September','Oktober','november','December');`

that will have it as index of 0

so when you grab it $swedish_months[$get_month] will zone into the index. Unless get_month is not numeric you will need to adjust the index look up accordingly. (ie: `array('00'=>'Januari',...)`